# Continuously-updated (running-count) output from a program reading from a pipeline

Tags: bash

How can I get continuously-updated output from a program that's reading from a pipeline? For example, let's say that this program were a version of `wc`:

```
$ ls | running_wc
```

So I'd like this to output instantly, e.g.

```
0 0 0
```

and then every time a new output line is received, it'd update again, e.g.

```
1 2 12
2 4 24
etc.
```

Of course my command isn't really `ls`, it's a process that slowly outputs data... I'd actually love to dynamically have it count matches and non matches, and sum this info up on a single line, e.g,

```
$ my_process | count_matches error
```

This would constantly update a single line of output with the matching and non matching counts, e.g.

```
$ my_process | count_matches error
0 5
```

then later on it might look like so, since it's found 2 matches and 10 non matching lines.

```
$ my_process | count_matches error
2 10
```

Comment: Please ask about your *real* question explicitly (in the title). It's very different from the `ls | wc` strawman, because that strawman implies that `wc` has to be used exactly as-is (can't be replaced with a different command with new logic).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - yeah i would have, but I couldnt think of a clear way to get it across in a question, other than what I said. Definitely an approximation, and not exactly what I wanted, but it's in the same ballpark, imho

Comment: ...I came in here expecting to have (or be able to add) an answer talking about how to wait for directory entries to be added or removed without polling, f/e; or why it's better not to trust `ls | wc` to be an accurate file count in the first place.

Comment: All good points! I didnt' realize the ins/outs of it...

Comment: ...does the updated title work for you?

Comment: yeah that's great... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd` will print out statistics if it receives a `SIGUSR1` signal, but neither `wc` nor `grep` does that. You'll need to re-implement them, more or less.

```
count_matches() {
    local pattern=$1
    local matches=0 nonmatches=0
    local line

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == *$pattern* ]]; then ((++matches)); else ((++nonmatches)); fi
        printf '\r%s %s' "$matches" "$nonmatches"
    done

    printf '\n'
}
```

Printing a carriage return `\r` each time causes the printouts to overwrite each other.

Most programs will switch from line buffering to full buffering when used in a pipeline. Your slow-running program should flush its output after each line to ensure the results are available immediately. Or if you can't modify it, you can often use `stdbuf -oL` to force programs that use C stdio to line buffer stdout.

```
stdbuf -oL my_process | count_matches error
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk. First we create the "`my_process`":

```
$ for i in {1..10} ; do echo $i ; sleep 1 ; done # slowly prints lines
```

The match counter:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {           
    print "match","miss"   # print header
    m=0                    # reset match count
}
{
    if($1~/(3|6)/)         # match is a 3 or 6 (for this output)
        m++                # increment match count
    print m,NR-m           # for each record output match / miss counts
}'
```

Running it:

```
$ for i in {1..10} ; do echo $i ; sleep 1 ; done | awk 'BEGIN{print "match","miss";m=0}{if($1~/(3|6)/)m++;print m,NR-m}'
match miss
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 4
2 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
```